# Is it possible to connect two devices on the internet if both are behind NAT using this method?

Tags: networking, internet, ip-address

If i understand NAT correctly, by default a device outside of the NAT cannot reach a device inside it. If the two devices use a central server to connect however they can obviously communicate. My question is whether it is possible to remove the central server after establishing the connection if the central server simply sends the IP and port that it is using for each device to the other device. In this case the two end devices could send messages directly to each other via this IP and port. Would this work?

If this doesn't work is there any other method to use a central server to establish a connection, but otherwise have the two devices communicate directly allowing the central connection to be closed.

Comment: With TCP no, with UDP see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

Answer (score 0):

This depends if the NAT is symmetric or not. Symmetric means that for every request from a specific host from the outside, the NAT responds with a specific port that can only be used from the ip that made that request.

If you just use this information from another host, it will not be able to reach the internal device. This means that all the traffic has to go through the host that made the initial request.

With WebRTC, [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) is basially what you are asking for. [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) is used in cases where STUN does not work.